I keep downloading an empty package when downloading fxcmpy package in python
I am trying to install the fxcmpy package however I keep installing the 0.0.0.1 version, using the below commands:
pip install fxcmpy
import fxcmpy
The package getting downloaded is completely empty, can someone please help me understand what is happening here and how can I download the correct package?

You can try:
pip install fxcmpy==<version_number>
If you have already downloaded it:
pip uninstall fxcmpy
pip install fxcmpy==<version_number>
If these don't work, you can probably look up some answers online.

Your fxcmpy package may depend on other packages or libraries that are not installed correctly. You need to check their official documentation or the dependency information on the PyPI page and install the dependency packages in advance.

The fxcmpy PyPI page says

Security Holding Package
This is a security holding package, a placeholder for a deleted package susceptible to hijacking.
(The package is completely empty)
[...]

From the above, it looks like fxcmpy has removed from PyPI.
You can try to install the package from source, cloning the GitHub repo (which actually has valid content in it). Follow the official documentation to do so.
